# djano support nested or flat values for a single field using single serializer

Tags: python, json, django, django-serializer

I have a `DateRangeSerializer` serializer that validates a payload.

```
import rest_framework.serializers as serializer

from django.conf import settings

class ValueNestedSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    lower = serializer.DateTimeField(input_formats=settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS, required=True)
    upper = serializer.DateTimeField(input_formats=settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS, required=True)
    

class DateRangeSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    attribute = serializer.CharField(default="UPLOAD_TIME", allow_null=True)
    operator = serializer.CharField(default="between_dates")
    value = ValueNestedSerializer(required=True) <---- this could be set to `False` to address the issue
    # lower = serializer.DateTimeField()
    # upper = serializer.DateTimeField()
    timezone = serializer.CharField(default="UTC")
    timezoneOffset = serializer.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The respective payload:

```
"date_range": {
        "attribute": "date_range",
        "operator": "between_dates",
        "value": {
            "lower": "2023-01-06T00:00:00Z",
            "upper": "2023-02-05T23:59:59Z"
        }
    }
```

Here `value` field is `nested`. But there are few implementations where `lower` and `upper` are `flat` values and not nested.

Like:

```
"date_range": {
        "lower": "2023-01-21T00:00:00Z",
        "upper": "2023-02-21T23:59:59Z"
    }
```

Now, I can set the `value required=False` and add `lower/upper` as flat fields like I've mentioned in the comments above. But I want to enforce it more "properly".

Is there any other way where I can handle both payloads for `nested` and `flat` lower-upper values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an [extra context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to the serializer, indicating if you want a flat response and modify the response by overriding [.to_representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) hook using such key (which I called `flat`):

serializers.py

```
class ValueNestedSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    lower = serializer.DateTimeField(input_formats=settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS, required=True)
    upper = serializer.DateTimeField(input_formats=settings.DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS, required=True)
    

class DateRangeSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    attribute = serializer.CharField(default="UPLOAD_TIME", allow_null=True)
    operator = serializer.CharField(default="between_dates")
    value = ValueNestedSerializer(required=True)
    timezone = serializer.CharField(default="UTC")
    timezoneOffset = serializer.IntegerField(default=0)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        flat = self.context.pop('flat', None)
        if flat:
            for key, value in representation['value'].items():
                representation[key] = value
            representation.pop('value')

        return representation
```

views.py example

```
class DateRangeAPIView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        value = {
            'lower': datetime.now(), 
            'upper': datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1, minutes=42, seconds=42)
        }
        data = {'attribute': 'date_range', 'operator': 'between_dates', 'value': value}

        serializer = DateRangeSerializer(data=data, context={'flat': True})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You can just ommit `context={'flat': True}` to get a normal response, e.g. `DateRangeSerializer(data=data)`.